# Reading in a tab-delimited file as a map instead of a list in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to read in a tab delimited file in Groovy...

```
inputFile.eachLine { rawLine ->

   def line = rawLine.split('\t')
   def orderId = line[0]
```

But instead of having to remember which field is at which column number, I would rather do something like...

```
 def orderId = line['ORDERID']
```

Right now if I try this it gives an exception..

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: 
Exception evaluating property 'ORDERID' for java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
```

I think its because I am reading in each record as a list and not a map. How can I read this same file as a map then?

Comment: Use a parser like https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv just set the delimiter to `\t`

Answer (score 1):

Given this tab-delimited file:

```
"City"  "Country"       "Year"
Paris   France  2016
Toronto Canada  2010
```

The following script uses Groovy 2.4.5 and [groovycsv](https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv) (as [tim_yates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6509/tim-yates) suggested; I just happen to be using it right now):

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.1')
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv

def file = args[0]
def text = new File(file).getText()

def data = parseCsv(text, separator: '\t')

data.each { line ->
    println "city: " + line["City"]
    println "country: " + line["Country"]
    println "year: " + line["Year"]
}
```

and `groovy MyScript.groovy my_file.csv` yields:

```
city: Paris
country: France
year: 2016
city: Toronto
country: Canada
year: 2010
```

Comment: `def data = parseCsv(text, separator: '\t')` is more idiomatic groovy

Comment: You also don't need the `def` in the line `data.each { def line ->`

Comment: And you should be able to do `println "city: ${line.City}"` I don't believe you need the `def fieldMap = line.toMap()` line

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a necro, but if anyone is interested in the "by hand" method, this will get you started.  I realize the above library is probably *better*, so this is here for educational purposes.

It will break if:

1. columns size != any particular record size
2. there is a blank line in the file

`FixtureMinion` is a class local to my test env, and using a classloader is clearly not the the only way to load a file.

This is used in some tests when I want data that looks like it came from a database without it actually being from a database. YMMV.

```
static List<Map<String, String>> listOfMapFromTabSeparatedFile(String resourcFile) {
    // The list where the maps are "accumulated"
    List<Map<String, String>> accumulator = []
    URL fileLocation = FixtureMinion.class.getClassLoader().getResource(resourcFile)
    new File(fileLocation.toURI()).withReader { reader ->
        // get the columns
        List<String> columns = splitOnTabs(reader.readLine())
        reader.eachLine { line ->
            List<String> record = splitOnTabs(line)
            assert columns.size() == record.size()
            // magic happens
            accumulator << [columns, record].transpose().collectEntries { it }
        }
    }
    accumulator
}

static List<String> splitOnTabs(String stringToSplit) {
    stringToSplit.split("\t", -1) as List<String>
}
```

Further, to explain the "magic" fire up the groovy shell

```
15:38 $ groovysh
Groovy Shell (2.4.9, JVM: 1.8.0_181)
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
-----------------------------------------------------
groovy:000> col = ['a','b','c']
===> [a, b, c]
groovy:000> rec = ['x','y','z']
===> [x, y, z]
groovy:000> [col, rec].transpose()
===> [[a, x], [b, y], [c, z]]
groovy:000> [col, rec].transpose().collectEntries {it}
===> [a:x, b:y, c:z]
```

`transpose` creates pairs here, and `collectEntries` turns them into a map.